# Windows 2003 vs Windows 2008 VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, vpn, rras

I'm having trouble to figure out something that Microsoft changed from Win 2003->2008 VPN. This is my setup:

**office #1**

```
subnet #1: 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0  
subnet #2: 10.202.0.0/255.255.0.0
Windows 7 as VPN client
```

**office #2**

```
subnet #1: 10.11.0.0/255.255.255.0
```

---

Problems:

1. A Windows 2008 Server with VPN/RRAS installed is in office #2. After connecting from office#1/subnet#1 to office #2/subnet#1 I cannot ping or access anything in office#1/subnet #2 from office#1/subnet#1
   route print shows that a route 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 is added
2. Windows 2003 Server VPN/RRAS installed in the office #2: everything works fine

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

See KB254231.

This is how Windows unfortunately now handles routes when given an IP via PPP. It decides to put a route in by its self and guess the subnet mask based on the old clasful system. Terrible pain the rear this is.

Cheers,
Gavin.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your VPN config is pushing a route for 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 to the clients. This means that all of your traffic for office 1 subnet 2 is attempting to traverse your VPN instead of staying local. To fix this, you should configure the route being pushed to your clients to be `10.11.0.0/255.255.255.0` so that it matches the subnet at the remote site.